# How to capture the PRINT event after a SELECT statement in ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Please, observe the following sample C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MyApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private const string SQL = "SELECT 10;PRINT 'OK'";

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var c = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;trusted_connection=yes"))
            {
                c.Open();
                c.InfoMessage += OnInfoMessage;
                c.Disposed += OnConnDisposed;

                Console.WriteLine("--- Select ---");
                Select(c, SQL);

                Console.WriteLine("--- Execute ---");
                Execute(c, SQL);

                Console.WriteLine("--- ExecuteScalar ---");
                ExecuteScalar(c, SQL);
            }
        }

        private static void Execute(SqlConnection c, string sql)
        {
            using (var cmd = c.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        private static void ExecuteScalar(SqlConnection c, string sql)
        {
            using (var cmd = c.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }

        private static void Select(SqlConnection c, string sql)
        {
            using (var cmd = c.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0));
                }
            }
        }

        private static void OnConnDisposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)sender;
            sqlConnection.InfoMessage -= OnInfoMessage;
            sqlConnection.Disposed -= OnConnDisposed;
        }

        private static void OnInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PRINT");
        }
    }
}
```

Running it produces the following output:

```
--- Select ---
10
--- Execute ---
PRINT
--- ExecuteScalar ---
10
```

As you can see, neither `Select` nor `ExecuteScalar` capture the `PRINT` event that follows the `SELECT 10` statement.

How can I cause `Select` (I do not care about `ExecuteScalar`, it is here for the sake of completeness) both get the result set and cause the PRINT event, like it does the `Execute` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing a batch (multiple statements) you have to loop through the resultsets when you `Execute` the command.

```
private static void Select(SqlConnection c, string sql)
{
    using (var cmd = c.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            do
            {
                if ( reader.Read() )
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0));
            }
            while ( reader.NextResult() );
        }
    }
}
```

`ExecuteScalar` will return the first value from the first row of the first resultset.

Comment: Stupid me, I never realised I had to call `reader.NextResult()`. That call returns `false`, because there is no next result, but by calling it I cause the PRINT event to be captured.